# Why is this jquery not changing the opacity?

Tags: jquery, html

My code is supposed to set the opacity of a div element from 0 to 1 when the user starts scrolling the body. It is not working for some reason.

```
$("bod").load(function(){
    document.getElementById("bodyHeader").style.opacity = "1";
});
```

Excuse the bad names :)

Comment: `load` does not do what you think it does in this instance, since you're calling it on a `bod` element (not on the `body` element. Also, `load` is not the appropriate event to listen for if you're looking for the event when a user starts scrolling...

Comment: "$("bod")" -> typo or error in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` have nothing to do with scrolling.

For scrolling the body you should use: `$(window).scroll(function () { ... })`

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
document.getElementById("something").style.opacity = "1";
})
```

```css
body {
height: 800px;
}

#something {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll to see the magic</p>
<div id="something">
</div>
```

**UPDATE ON YOUR COMMENT:**
If you need to do it after scrolling some pixels you should use: `$(window).scrollTop()`

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
if($(window).scrollTop() > 40 && $(window).scrollTop() <= 80){
document.getElementById("something").style.opacity = "0.5";
}
else if($(window).scrollTop() > 80 && $(window).scrollTop() <= 120){
document.getElementById("something").style.opacity = "0.7";
}
else if($(window).scrollTop() > 120){
document.getElementById("something").style.opacity = "1";
}
})
```

```css
body {
height: 800px;
}

#something {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll to see the magic</p>
<div id="something">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to slow it down? I don't want it to be instantaneous.

Comment: @RobCC Updated the answer. Read after "UPDATED ON YOUR COMMENT"